# How to find out correct Sri Yantra?

Tags: sri-vidya, yantra

I have been looking around for correct **Sri Yantra** for some time but not sure which one is the right one to be used. Some of them are:

1. Black & White, circular with petals & triangles
2. Colored, circular with petals & triangles
3. Black & White, circular with petals & triangles but have square boundary with T shaped openings at the center of each side of square.
4. Colored, circular with petals & triangles but have square boundary with T shaped openings at the center of each side of square.

Also I would like to know the correct way of using it. If possible I would like to know if there are some scriptures associated with this yantra. Thanks.

Comment: There are many scriptures which talk of it but one should be initiated into the vidya in order to become eligible for pooja. There is detailed worship in nityotsava and also texts like yogini hridayam. Setu bandha

Comment: @RakeshJoshi 'one should be initiated into the vidya' you mean to say by some Guru?

Comment: yes. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17730/7853

Comment: @RakeshJoshi just a thought ... can the paper printout of it be used for meditation sake?

Comment: yes even softcopy can be used. The more you visualize the better it is. Try to visualize circles and triangles etc ...

Comment: Just go for simple outline ShtiYantra. The coloured ones are maybe just to attract peoples eyes to buy it, or maybe produced by some Sect of worshipper which we do not know. The basic Shri Chakra is but just outline one. Also, the square type boundary with T ending, is called Bhoopura भूपुर, which is often made with all yantras. So do get Shri Chakra with bhupura.

Comment: The coloured ones are maybe just to attract peoples eyes to buy it -- No some texts prescribe those color fillings. That's why they are there. But some other texts don't so both are potent. We just need to check if the triangles, lotus petals and the enclosure are drawn properly or not. @AnuragSingh

Comment: @Rickross yes. True. For normal people the basic outline one should be taken, as those colored petals, triangles, with mantra and beeja mantra are so complex and should be deciphered only under guru or some reliable text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following image is a correct form of Sri Yantra. But some other forms are also correct.

[image]

Quoting from [Astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/scpooja.htm), from where the image is taken:

> Shree Chakra pooja or Yantra Pooja is the worship of a deity in a
>   diagrammatic form. This type of worship exists in a lot of the other
>   parts of the world also. To enjoy the benefits of Shri Chakra Pooja,
>   you need to know Chakra puja vidhi. But, before we proceed further me
>   must know the power of Sri Chakra and How to worship Sri chakra.
>
> The worship of Devi in Shreechakra Pooja is regarded as the highest
>   form of the Devi worship. Originally Lord Shiva gave 64 Chakras and
>   their Shree Chakra Mantras to the world, to attain various spiritual
>   and material benefits. For his consort, Devi he gave the Shreechakra
>   Yantra and the highly coveted and the most powerful Shodashakshari
>   mantra, which is the equivalent of all the other 64 Shree Chakras put
>   together.

So, Sri Vidya and Sri Yantra worship are serious Sadhanas. One should be initiated into it and only then he is considered qualified to perform them.

One can do devotional worship however, like offering incense, lighted lamps and food items to the Yantra, as per one's capabilities.

You can take a print out of the image and frame it and then offer it devotional services like mentioned.

You can also meditate on the 9 triangles, each one of which is presided by one of the 9 forms of Goddess Lalita, like Tripura Devi, Tripureshi Devi, Tripura Siddha, Tripura Amba etc. In the Bindu (dot) of the inner most triangle resides Kameswara Sahita Lalita Mahatripura Sundari (that is the Goddess along with Shiva).

> If possible I would like to know if there are some scriptures
>   associated with this yantra. Thanks.

Yes, there are many texts and scriptures. **Nityotshava** is one such text, which was composed by one of Bhaskararaya's disciple, and is considered an authority on the subject of Sri Vidya rituals.

And scriptures include- **Dakshinamurty Samhita, Jyanarnava Tantram, Sri Krama, Tantraraja Tantram, Yogini Hridaya** etc.

Nitoyoshodashika Arnava Tantram also gives details of how to form the Sri Yantra. The other great compilation Text called Tantrasara also quotes from  various scriptures as regards how to do draw this Yantra, what materials to be used, who are qualified to draw it and what are the errors, what should not be done during installation, at what times it should be drawn and etc.

*Also note- If you keep this Yantra in your home along with some other Yantras, then **you have keep the Sri Yantra at the right of all of them**, as it is regarded as the greatest of all Yantras. And, the presiding deity of the Yantra is Sri Lalita Mahatripurasundari, who is also known as Sri Rajarajeswari.*

Comment: is colored one more effective than the black n white ones?

Comment: No both are potent. Some texts prescribe color fillings while some don't. @Just_Do_It

Comment: @Just_Do_It See my question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/are-the-sri-yantras-that-are-devoid-of-color-fillings-defective

Comment: my main motive of using it is for meditation, do I still need to perform the puja etc stated by you above? Sorry for bogging you.

Comment: No it's upto you what u want to do. There are no rules for you because you are not initiated yet (which i have assumed). So, u can skip puja and all and perform just the meditation. @Just_Do_It

Comment: How do I get initiated, do I need to seek a guru or is there a process for this? Can you guide me (we can chat if needed). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, initiation (diksha) means taking the mantra duly from the Guru, who belongs to the Sri Vidya tradtioan and who is carrying the mantra forward to u in an unbroken chain from the 1st guru who is the Adinatha (or lOrd Shiva). So, u have to look for ur Guru in the city u reside. Some org mite give u Diksha over phone too. Like these:@Just_Do_It

Comment: .... https://srividyasadhana.com/   http://srividya.org/about/temple-founder/ ... And even the owner of Astrojyoti.com can initiate u over phone if u ask him. @Just_Do_It

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71245/discussion-between-just-do-it-and-rickross).